# Pymupdf Insert_image : TypeError takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Tags: python, pdf, pdf-generation

The code below raises `TypeError: insert_image() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given`. Can someone tell me how to fix it?

```
class PDFEditor:
    def __init__(self, input_pdf_path):
        self.pdf_document = fitz.open(input_pdf_path)

    def add_image(self, page_number, image_path):
        pdf_page = self.pdf_document[page_number - 1]
        rect1 = fitz.Rect(100, 100, 200, 200)
        pdf_page.insert_image(rect1, image_path, keep_proportion=True, overlay=True)

    def add_text(self, page_number, x, y, text_to_add, font_name='Helvetica', font_size=12):
        pdf_page = self.pdf_document[page_number - 1]
        pdf_page.insert_text((x, y), text_to_add, fontsize=font_size, fontname=font_name)

    def save(self, output_pdf_path):
        self.pdf_document.save(output_pdf_path)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    poa_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'example.pdf')
    pdf_editor = PDFEditor(poa_path)
    pdf_editor.add_image(page_number=2, image_path='screenshot example.jpg')
    pdf_editor.save('test.pdf')
```

I tried to delete or add `self` in different place, like front of `pdf_page`. But it didn't change. At the same time, method `add_text` works well. So I really feel confused..

Comment: Only `rect` can be passed as a positional argument for `insert_image`. `image_path` needs to be passed as a keyword, most likely `filename=...`, [`Page.insert_image()`](https://pymupdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/page.html#Page.insert_image)